# Printer is automatically detected but when i print any document it cannot perform any function. Message on screen says "printing completed"

Tags: printing, hp

using Ubuntu 18.04, printer Hp laserjet p1005

```
$ hp-check

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.10)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Note: hp-check can be run in three modes:
1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the
HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the proper dependencies
are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.
2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro
supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP supplied tarball
has the proper dependencies installed to successfully run.
3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode
will check both of the above cases (both compile- and run-time dependencies).

Check types:
a. EXTERNALDEP - External Dependencies
b. GENERALDEP - General Dependencies (required both at compile and run time)
c. COMPILEDEP - Compile time Dependencies
d. [All are run-time checks]
PYEXT SCANCONF QUEUES PERMISSION

Status Types:
    OK
    MISSING - Missing Dependency or Permission or Plug-in
    INCOMPAT - Incompatible dependency-version or Plugin-version

warning: 12-18.04 version is not supported. Using 12-17.04 versions dependencies to verify and install...

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux
 Host: ola-HP-Pavilion-Notebook
 Proc: 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 18.04
 Bitness: 64 bit

-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.17.10
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
warning: HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is not supported for 12 distro 18.04 version

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf. Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.17.10

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd/hplip
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-doc
icon=no
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=yes
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=yes
foomatic-drv-install=yes
foomatic-ppd-install=yes
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.17.10
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt5
qt3=no
qt4=no
qt5=yes
policy-kit=yes
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=no

Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: No such file or directory

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[last_used]
device_uri = hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_P1005?serial=BC0VGMA

[installation]
date_time = 05/16/20 17:06:33
version = 3.17.10

 <Package-name> <Package-Desc> <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status> <Comment>

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 error: cups CUPS - Common Unix Printing System REQUIRED 1.1 - INCOMPAT 'CUPS may not be installed or not running'
 gs GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED 7.05 9.26 OK -
 error: xsane xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE OPTIONAL 0.9 - MISSING 'xsane needs to be installed'
 scanimage scanimage - Shell scanning program OPTIONAL 1.0 1.0.27 OK -
 error: dbus DBus - Message bus system REQUIRED - 1.12.2 MISSING 'DBUS may not be installed or not running'
 policykit PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework OPTIONAL - 0.105 OK -
 network network -wget OPTIONAL - 1.19.4 OK -
 avahi-utils avahi-utils OPTIONAL - 0.7 OK -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 error: libjpeg libjpeg - JPEG library REQUIRED - - MISSING 'libjpeg needs to be installed'
 error: cups-devel CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files REQUIRED - - MISSING 'cups-devel needs to be installed'
 error: cups-image CUPS image - CUPS image development files REQUIRED - - MISSING 'cups-image needs to be installed'
 error: libpthread libpthread - POSIX threads library REQUIRED - b'2.27' MISSING 'libpthread needs to be installed'
 error: libusb libusb - USB library REQUIRED - 1.0 MISSING 'libusb needs to be installed'
 sane SANE - Scanning library REQUIRED - - OK -
 error: sane-devel SANE - Scanning library development files REQUIRED - - MISSING 'sane-devel needs to be installed'
 error: libnetsnmp-devel libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED 5.0.9 - MISSING 'libnetsnmp-devel needs to be installed'
 error: libcrypto libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library REQUIRED - 1.1.1 MISSING 'libcrypto needs to be installed'
 python3X Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language REQUIRED 2.2 3.6.9 OK -
 error: python3-notify2 Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL - - MISSING 'python3-notify2 needs to be installed'
 error: python3-pyqt4-dbus PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4 OPTIONAL 4.0 - MISSING 'python3-pyqt4-dbus needs to be installed'
 error: python3-pyqt4 PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x) REQUIRED 4.0 - MISSING 'python3-pyqt4 needs to be installed'
 python3-dbus Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus REQUIRED 0.80.0 1.2.6 OK -
 python3-xml Python XML libraries REQUIRED - 2.2.5 OK -
 error: python3-devel Python devel - Python development files REQUIRED 2.2 3.6.9 MISSING 'python3-devel needs to be installed'
 python3-pil PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL - 1.1.7 OK -
 python3-reportlab Reportlab - PDF library for Python OPTIONAL 2.0 3.4.0 OK -

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 error: libtool libtool - Library building support services REQUIRED - - MISSING 'libtool needs to be installed'
 error: gcc gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler REQUIRED - - MISSING 'gcc needs to be installed'
 error: make make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs REQUIRED 3.0 - MISSING 'make needs to be installed'

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 cupsext CUPS-Extension REQUIRED - 3.17.10 OK -
 hpmudext IO-Extension REQUIRED - 3.17.10 OK -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

'/etc/sane.d/dll.d/hpaio' not found.
 hpaio HPLIP-SANE-Backend REQUIRED - 3.17.10 OK 'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
 scanext Scan-SANE-Extension REQUIRED - 3.17.10 OK -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

No Scanner found.

--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

  Device URI Model
  -------------------------------- -----------------
  hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_P1005?serial HP LaserJet P1005
  =BC0VGMA

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------

HP-LaserJet-P1005
-----------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_P1005?serial=BC0VGMA
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-P1005.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/HP-LaserJet-P1005.ppd ppd file
PPD Description:
Printer status: printer HP-LaserJet-P1005 is idle. enabled since و 16:34:31 PKT ت 16 مئی 2020
error: Required plug-in status: Not installed
Communication status: Good

--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

USB HP-LaserJet-P1005 Required - - OK Node:'/dev/bus/usb/002/015' Perm:' root lp rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'

-----------
| SUMMARY |
-----------

Missing Required Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'libcups2' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'libdbus-1-dev' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'libjpeg-dev' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'libcups2-dev' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'cups-bsd' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'cups-client' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'libcupsimage2-dev' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'build-essential' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'libusb-1.0.0-dev' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'libsane-dev' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'libsnmp-dev' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'snmp-mibs-downloader' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'openssl' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'python3-pyqt4' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'python3-dev' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'libtool' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'libtool-bin' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'build-essential' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'build-essential' package is missing/incompatible

Missing Optional Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'xsane' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'python3-notify2' package is missing/incompatible
error: 'python3-dbus.mainloop.qt' package is missing/incompatible

Plug-in Status
--------------
error: Plug-ins need to be installed

Total Errors: 19
Total Warnings: 0

Done.
```

THEN

I downloaded and installed Hplip 3.20.05 by replacing ver. 3.17.10

After restart I got the message HPLIP Status Service "No system tray detected on this system" Unable to start, exiting.

When I plugged the printer in, popup message says "Driver Plug-in Required"

I clicked next but failed to install Plug-in

When I run 'hp-plugin' command in the terminal, it gives the result as follows:

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.5)
Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.5)
Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Gtk-Message: 11:52:07.868: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Checking for network connection...
Downloading plug-in from:
Plugin is not accessible. Trying to download it from fallback location: [https://developers.hp.com/sites/default/files/hplip-3.20.5-plugin.run]
Receiving digital keys: /usr/bin/gpg --homedir /home/ola/.hplip/.gnupg --no-permission-warning --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 0x4ABA2F66DBD5A95894910E0673D770CDA59047B9

Done.
```

Comment: then i downloaded and installed Hplip 3.20.05 by replacing ver. 3.17.10

Comment: After restart i also get the message HPLIP Status Service "No system tray detected on this system" Unable to start, exiting.

Comment: Please open a pdf/ image file in firefox browser and send print. Please tell if it prints anything. I am also facing this kind of problems. I had to reset the printer or remove and replug the USB cable before sending second print.  I What resolved my problem was system update.

Comment: When i plugged the printer in, popup message says "Driver Plug-in Required"
i clicked next but failed to install Plug-in

Comment: @Ajay same problem even if i try to print from firefox browser

Comment: in order to get rid of this message Gtk-Message: 11:52:07.868: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" i applied command in terminal apt-get install -s --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module but problem persists

Comment: then i tried following command to resolve the error "sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386" but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer This page [HP LaserJet p1005 Printer](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_p1005) it says

> This printer REQUIRES a downloadable driver plug-in

Now refer this post here is the solution you need.
[How to install printer drivers for HP Laserjet P1005 in Ubuntu 15.04 without needing access to openprinting.org website and without using buggy hplip drivers](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/foo2zjs/+question/269457)

> Please use the following install procedure instead:
>
> **> # How to install printer drivers for HP Laserjet P1005 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit without needing access to open printing.org website and without using buggy hplip drivers**
>   **> #List of printers supported by foo2zjs printer driver: http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/**
>   **> # Copy-paste following Terminal commands one by one into the Terminal:**

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get remove hplip cups-filters cups hplip-data system-config-printer-udev
 sudo apt-get install build-essential tix groff dc axel cups
 sudo apt-get install cups-filters unp system-config-printer-gnome
 sudo rm -rf /usr/share/hplip
 cd /tmp
 rm foo*
 axel http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz
 unp foo2zjs.tar.gz
 cd foo2zjs/
 make
 ./getweb P1005 # Get HP LaserJet P1005 firmware file !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 sudo make install
 sudo make install-hotplug
 # Unplug and re-plug the USB printer into the PC
 # add new HP Laserjet P1005 printer via system-config-printer tool
 # and choose to use foo2zjs foomatic printer driver :
 system-config-printer
 # check /var/log/syslog for any errors related to foo2zjs driver:
 tail /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: After applying these commands, when i plug-in the printer it was installed automatically and working fine. Thank you for providing such a valuable solution  @Ajay